# Just got a job title for something that I've been doing for 2 years

Tags: resume

About 2 years ago my job migrated into something different and I trained a new person to do what I was doing.  I started and I started doing reporting, etc for my group.  However, what I was doing didn't actually exist as an official position and the thought was it was still developing so it would be difficult to go to HR and ask for a new title.  We finally took a suggested title to HR and I recently 'officially' got my new title.  How do I put it on my resume?  Do I artificially cut off the end date of my last role to about when I transferred jobs?  If so, my work record won't match what I have on my resume if a company calls my current office to inquire.

Suggestions?  Is there an official way to indicate you were doing 2 jobs concurrently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ethical to put a job title representing the work I actually performed instead of my given title on a resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27691/is-it-ethical-to-put-a-job-title-representing-the-work-i-actually-performed-inst)

Answer (score 1):

You can clearly state that fact in the description of your previous position, as in "also performing the duties of XYZ since ...", and put the XYZ on actual date of changing the position.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I artificially cut off the end date of my last role to about when I
>   transferred jobs?

No.

That would be misleading at best, and a lie at worst. A reference check or background check would show the mismatch and could be embarrassing.

> Is there an official way to indicate you were doing 2 jobs
>   concurrently?

You weren't doing 2 jobs concurrently. You were doing one job that had elements of two different roles.

You list your job, along with the title you held and the dates involved, and use bullet points to describe all the elements of both roles.

Then you list your new job and title with the date it started. You use bullet points to describe that role.